# Stop manual edit in Combo Box, WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I can't find anything on this, but is there a way to stop the user being able to click inside a `ComboBox`?

This is what is happening at the moment,

[image]

Is there a way to disable this?

EDIT: After implementing `IsEditable` I am still getting this result, however, nothing happens when I press enter etc. But I can still add text to the combobox

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the IsEditable property of the ComboBox to false: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.iseditable(v=vs.110).aspx

This will disable the editing of the text in text box of the ComboBox.

Comment: Then there is *something* wrong with your XAML markup. It is of course impossible for anyone to point out what without seeing it and the rest of your code. Please provide a repo of your issue. A picture doesn't help much I am afraid.

Comment: I found the answer was that in the `Combo Box` Styles, I had style setup for the `TextBox` and I had to set it to `<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>`

Answer (score 0):

Set the **IsReadOnly** property of your ComboBox to true. ([Documentation here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.combobox.isreadonly(v=vs.110).aspx)) If that still doesn't help, there might be something wrong in your xaml as @mm8 mentioned before.

Answer (score 0):

For future reference of people who may get stuck with `IsEditable property`. The issue was with the `Styles` for the `TextBox` part of the `CombBox`.

I had to add this to the `Style` of the `TextBox`

```
<Setter Property="IsEnabled" Value="False"/>
```

This not being set was overriding the `IsEditable property` on the `ComboBox` styles and on the `CombBox` itself.